# vbscript for WQL WMI with or operator

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wql

1. i am querying for event viewer log using vbscript.

   1. When I try ot use OR operator @ Where Logfile='System' Or 'Application' it gives info but drops TYPE condition and i found my results with information type data.
   2. How do i combine this two queries so that I don't have to write
      extra code.

```
Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'Application'  AND Type <> 'Information' AND TimeGenerated >  ' " & dteDate & "' ")
```

```
Set colLoggedEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile = 'System'  AND Type <> 'Information' AND TimeGenerated >  ' " & dteDate & "' ")
```

regards : msinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parentheses for an inner comparison.

> Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent Where ( Logfile = 'System' Or Logfile = 'Application' ) AND Type <> 'Information' AND TimeGenerated >  '" & dteDate & "'

Comment: Thanks! It opened my eyes, I was putting parentheses before Where keyword in actual code. :-)